# Make #content tag in Wordpress Page 100% in width and height w/ background image resizes to the browser

Tags: wordpress, html, post, background-image

I created a page in Wordpress.  I need the #content to be 100% width and height with a background image that resizes as the browser window changes.

Any recommendations how to achieve this?

Erik

Answer (score 0):

In your style sheet:

```
#content {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:url(path_to_your_image.png) no-repeat top center;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

The height working might be tricky. You could just add to your style sheet file as well...

```
html {
    height:100%;
}
```

or if that doesn't do it try this...

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
}
```

..and hopefully it doesn't cause any other problems.